# Multi-Cursor editing with QScintilla

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscintilla

I'd like to create a little QScintilla widget supporting multi-cursor-editing like in SublimeText. As far as i know Scintilla already supports multiple cursors but I haven't seen any example out there.

So, could anyone please post a little example showing the basics of multiple cursors with QScintilla?

Comment: Why not try to create an example yourself, and add it to your question? Then you can explain which specific parts of the *actual code* you're having difficulty with.

Comment: @ekhumoro Sure, that'd be a good starting point, problem is I don't know which methods related to what I'm asking is providing QScintilla. Said otherwise, in which part of the documentation I can find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multi-cursor feature is available in Scintilla, but QScintilla doesn't provide direct wrappers for this feature. However, you can "reimplement" your wrappers, since almost everything can be done with the `SendScintilla` method.

```
from PyQt5.Qsci import QsciScintilla
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication([])

ed = QsciScintilla()

ed.setText('insert <-\nsome <-\ntext <-\n')
ed.show()

# typing should insert in all selections at the same time
ed.SendScintilla(ed.SCI_SETADDITIONALSELECTIONTYPING, 1)

# do multiple selections
offset = ed.positionFromLineIndex(0, 7) # line-index to offset
ed.SendScintilla(ed.SCI_SETSELECTION, offset, offset)
# using the same offset twice selects no characters, hence a cursor

offset = ed.positionFromLineIndex(1, 5)
ed.SendScintilla(ed.SCI_ADDSELECTION, offset, offset)

offset = ed.positionFromLineIndex(2, 5)
ed.SendScintilla(ed.SCI_ADDSELECTION, offset, offset)

app.exec_()
```

You should wrap the `SendScintilla` calls in your own wrappers.

Keep in mind that the `offset`s are expressed in bytes and thus depend on the encoding of the text, which is more or less hidden by QScintilla's QStrings. On the other hand, the "line-index" are expressed in characters (codepoints if using unicode), and thus are more reliable.

Comment: Thank you very much! this answer is a very good starting point in order to start emulating sublime text behaviour using QScintilla. One additional question though, when I use tabs it kinda works alright. Problem appears when i press the arrow keys or i try to select words using shift, in that case the multicursors dissapear. Any workaround for this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change the selection as you intend it. Maybe you can catch keyboard events and reperform SETSELECTION/ADDSELECTION yourself. It seems suboptimal but I'm not sure there's another way.

Comment: Ok, that was offtopic, I'll accept your answer cos it's a good starting point to get rolling, thank you