# Drawing a cursor-like object in PyQt5 in python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am stuck trying to draw something that looks just like the normal blinking cursor in the textEdit in terms of position with respect to character. I need this because I am trying to display the postion of multiple users working simultaneously on the same document (something like Google Docs).
How can I draw more than one cursor at the same time?

Comment: You said that you're stuck in trying. Can you provide us the code you've got so far, even if it doesn't properly works as expected? Consider that you should be able to give us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

QScintilla can support multiple cursors [Multi-Cursor editing with QScintilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850277/multi-cursor-editing-with-qscintilla?rq=1) I expect the support doesn't require the workaround from that question anymore as the question is so old, though I'm not sure how well the api is suited to separate people making edits concurrently. I'd likely grab a GUI component that already supports multiple cursors (like QScintilla,) then wrap that in a facade that ensures edits are only actioned by the correct cursor something like (pseudo python):

```
keypress_event(event):
    control.disable_all_but_local_cursor()
    control.send_event(event)
    control.enable_cursors(remote_cursors)
```

A facade can also work around a textEdit control but you'd have to track the cursor positions and draw the cursors as a supported character like maybe U+2588 the unicode block. either way you'll need to tell the controls when remote cursors move and action it appropriately.